# Convert object to string pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I have a dataframe which has a column with the name 'Discipline', and it has the data type 'object'. I want to convert object to string and so I applied the expression:

```
data['Discipline'] = data['Discipline'].astype(str)
```

But now data in 'Discipline' has only Cyrillic letters

But after that the datatype is still object.

What else can I try to get the intended result?

Comment: As per the suggested duplicate, you can use `data['Discipline'] = data['Discipline'].astype('string')`.

Comment: An object is a string. So you don't need to convert. It seems you have an encoding problem. Add sample of your data